# Pinia stores not reactive in Vue3 components

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, store, pinia, vue-reactivity

I am using Pinia for stores in my Vue3 app with Typescript. I want to manage the current week that is being displayed. The problem arises when I try to access the `weekDisplay` variable from the store. It does not update its value when `currentDate` is modified, even though it is wrapped inside `computed()`. The `changeDisplay()` function is called from the `PageHeader` component, when certain buttons are pressed.

Note that `currentDate` is updated properly both inside the store and the component.

This is `src/stores/Activities.ts`:

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { computed, ref } from "vue";
import { weekName } from "@/main";
... /* Types, enums etc. */
export const useActivitiesStore = defineStore("activities", () => {
  const eventsMap = ref<Map<string, Activity[]>>(new Map());
  const currentDate = ref<Date>(new Date());
  const weekDisplay = computed(() => weekName(currentDate.value));
  function changeDisplay(change: number): void {
    currentDate.value.setDate(currentDate.value.getDate() + 7 * change);
  }
  return { eventsMap, currentDate, weekDisplay, changeDisplay };
});
```

This is `src/components/PageHeader.vue`:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
... /* Other imports */
import { useActivitiesStore } from "@/stores/Activities";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import { computed } from "vue";

let store = useActivitiesStore();

const { eventsMap, currentDate, weekDisplay } = storeToRefs(store);
</script>

<template>
  <header id="header">
    ...
    <section id="week-navigation-container" class="week-navigation">
      <article
        id="previous-week-button"
        class="week-button"
        @click="store.changeDisplay(-1)">
        <IconLeftArrow class="left-arrow" />
        <Tooltip text="Previous week" />
      </article>
      <article id="open-calendar-button" class="week-display">
        <h1 class="font-menu-title">
          {{ weekDisplay }}
        </h1>
        <Tooltip text="Open calendar" />
      </article>
      <article
        id="next-week-button"
        class="week-button"
        @click="store.changeDisplay(1)">
        <IconRightArrow class="right-arrow" />
        <Tooltip text="Next week" />
      </article>
    </section>
  </header>
</template>
```

This is `src/main.ts`:

```js
import "./assets/main.css";

import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

const pinia = createPinia();
const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);
app.use(pinia);
app.mount("#app");

export function datesArr(date: Date) {
  ...
}

export function weekName(date: Date): string {
  ...
}

export function dayToTop(day: number) {
  ...
}

export function timeToLeft(hour: number, minute: number, second: number) {
  ...
}

export function timeToWidth(hour: number, minute: number) {
  ...
}
```

The text inside the `h1` element with the `.font-menu-title` class should update when the buttons are pressed to display the relevant information. (The exact value would be the result of `weekName(currentDate)`, which should always be stored in the `weekDisplay` variable).

Answer (score 2):

Updating the date with `setDate` is an inplace replacement which Vue reactivity can't detect. It's not ideal looking code but you can alter the line to include an assignment and guarantee the reactivity response is triggered:

```js
function changeDisplay(change: number): void {
  currentDate.value = new Date(
    currentDate.value.setDate(currentDate.value.getDate() + 7 * change)
  )
}
```